CloudFormation code that retrieves specific values based on conditions
I want to create an IAM user that acquires the Assumerole. In the case of the uat environment, I want it to acquire the Assumerole for the 123451234512 account, and in the case of stg, I want it to acquire the Assumerole for the 123451234513 account, using a specific AccountId depending on the environment.
When I write the code as below and execute it in CloudFormation, I get below error.
Error Details:
Resource handler returned message: "Syntax errors in policy. (Service: Iam, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 8c2edcc6-0050-424a-8d3f-585102asd1t)" (RequestToken: 45930d92-bb77-c55a-c02a-06529728afs, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Code:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Create test User
Parameters:
  NetworkEnvironment:
    Description: test
    Type: String
    Default: uat
    AllowedValues:
      - uat
      - stg
      - prd

Mappings:
  AccountMap:
    uat:
      AccountId: "123451234512"
    stg:
      AccountId: "123451234513"
    prd:
      AccountId: "123451234514"

Resources:
  User01:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Path: /
      UserName: !Sub ${NetworkEnvironment}-test-user
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${NetworkEnvironment}-asd
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Sub ${NetworkEnvironment}

  Policy01:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Sub ${NetworkEnvironment}-test-policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:PutLogEvents
              - logs:GetLogEvents
            Resource: '*'
      Users:
        - !Ref User01

  Policy02:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Sub ${NetworkEnvironment}-test-assume-role
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Resource: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${!FindInMap [AccountMap, !Ref NetworkEnvironment, AccountId]}:role/testbucket1209
      Users:
        - !Ref User01

Can somebody help me on this? Thanks!

Can you include the entire error message into the question? The full error message should include a status code and an error code, and at least two other properties. If you remove PolicyR1 or PolicyR2, does the problem still occur, or is the error specific to a configuration with multiple policies?

@SmellyCat
I added the entire error message to the body. Policy01 is fine, but Policy02 has a problem.
There seems to be an issue with the way the code below is written, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Resource: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${!FindInMap [AccountMap, !Ref NetworkEnvironment, AccountId]}:role/testbucket1209

We encountered this issue a few days ago, and were able to overcome it with:
Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'

This allows you to nest intrinsic functions within FindInMap. Not only were we able to use If to select the key to look up, we were able to nest two FindInMap calls.
This first example uses a Cloudformation Condition to decide which production KMS key to lookup in the Mapping:
Principal:
  AWS:
  - !Sub
    - arn:aws:iam::${ProdKMSId}:root
    - ProdKMSId: !FindInMap [ 'KMSIds', !If [ IsSpecialAccount, 'specialkey', 'normalkey' ], "ProdKMSId" ]

This second example uses one FindInMap (using AccountId) to determine the type of account (special or not) and then use that string as the key in the second FindInMap.
Principal:
  AWS:
  - !Sub
    - arn:aws:iam::${ProdKMSId}:root
    - ProdKMSId: !FindInMap [ 'KMSIds', !FindInMap [ 'AccountTypes', !Ref AWS::AccountId, 'AccountType' ], "ProdKMSId" ]

